# My system does not restrict login if admin

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have the following code to check the login:

```
 class User extends Password {
 private $_db;
 function __construct($db) {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->_db = $db;
 }
 private function get_user_hash($user) {
  try {
   $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT admin_id, user, pass FROM boss WHERE user = :user AND type = "admin"');
   $stmt->execute(array('user' => $user));

   return $stmt->fetch();

  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
  }
 }
 public function login($user,$password) {
  $row = $this->get_user_hash($user);
  if($this->password_verify($password,$row['pass']) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];  
      return true;
  }
 }
 public function logout() {
  session_destroy();
 }
 public function is_logged_in() {
  if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
   return true;
  }
 }
}
$user = new User($db);
```

everything works properly, the problem is that I have two directories "admin" and "user" within each are "the same files" with the only difference that in each folder is a different query within settings:

admin: `SELECT admin_id, user, pass FROM Boss WHERE user = :user AND type = "admin"`

user: `SELECT admin_id, user, pass FROM users WHERE user =:user AND type = "user"`

when change /admin to /user my verification code (above) should distinguish whether or not an admin. since it does not, it passes the session and continued access as checking think so.

On each page "private" I put the following:

```
if ($user-> is_logged_in()) {header ('Location: user-area.php');}
```

What should I do?

If you need more code to find the solution just do it know.

I think the problem is in the function function "is_logged_in" because it would have to modify the configuration file admin to check otherwise if admin for example (not like doing something):

```
public function is_logged_in_admin() {
  if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true && $row['type'] == "admin") {
   return true;
  }
 }
```

and then check: `if($user->is_logged_in_admin()){header('Location: index.php?ruta=panel');}`

It would be nice, or what would be the right way?

Comment: Based on the user id do you have a way of knowing whether it should be admin or not?

Comment: @slopeofhope Yes. table "boss" has a row for "Type" (type = "admin")

Comment: So then why cant u make a function to check if the user is admin and set the flag like the following $_SESSION['admin'] = True or False

Comment: @slopeofhope Could you help me with the function?

Comment: Just think this through..u just told me you have a way of checking to see if the user is admin or not via user id. So the result can be only true or false. And what is the input u are using..user_id.

Comment: Umm ... where is this code `$this->password_verify()`  I'd wager the most important method here, did you forget to code it perhaps ... lol  ... or is it inherited ... I don't know.

Comment: Your code wont distinguish, how does `$row['type']` magically appear in `is_logged_in_admin()` ?  It's in a total different scope.. you should check inside that method, or set a flag in session when loggin happens.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I can not, and try to put $_SESSION['admin'] = True; inside if($this->password_verify($password,$row['contrasena']) == 1) {

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I very much regret not being able to understand everything they say, I'm very new to PHP and am trying to understand this code to download, it will completely understand English and I use google translator. I have 6 hours fighting with this problem, I hope resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Your making it harder then it has to be, All you need to do is copy your oringal users class and make the following changes

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class Admin extends Password{
    private $_db;
    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
    private function get_user_hash($username){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, adminID FROM admin WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            //copy user table, name admin, change memberID to adminID
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
    public function login($username,$password){
        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['adminID'] = $row['adminID']; //change to adminID
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }
    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Then create a totally separate login/logout page for admins only.  If you need to check for admin, its simply `isset($_SESSION['adminID'])`, if you need to check for a user its `isset($_SESSION['memberID'])`, if you need to see if they are logged in regardless of admin or member its `isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])`

This way 99% of your code can be converted to the admin side, simply by changing the table based on what ID is in the session.

```
 $table = 'user';

 if(isset($_SESSION['memberID'])){
     $table = 'admin';
 }
```

As an added benefit of having separate logins, you could easily make a login as user function for admins that doesn't use the password.  If you use the same session data for both that is impossible.

Comment: unless this is only for admins then you can ignore that ... lol

Comment: Can not get it to work, but could rise to GitHub do not think you have time to check out :(

Comment: This is the original project: https://github.com/daveismyname/loginregister

Comment: This is for both admin and normal users? yes?

Comment: That original project only provides for general users, what I did to create Admin was to copy all files in "/ admin" and change the query settings to select the new table "admin" which is formed in the same way that "members".

Comment: Well, the admin table has a modification, members have the "active" row and the change admin "type" where 1 is admin and 0 no.

Comment: You want to turn up the project that I have a Git? The problem is me modify many terms to Spanish.

Comment: That's confusing, I would build them using the same table, or do completely separate code for each one.  As well as separate session variables.  I had assumed you just added a field named type into a user table.

Comment: No sorry I don't work for free,  I don't mind providing a bit of help here and there ... but much more then that and it becomes work ... lol ... also I don't know a lick of Spanish.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for all the help, how much to solve this problem so that you know Git lines changed since my idea is to learn. I would also like that will verify if there is problem in the code, which can break and allow others access to some.